# HTTP 404.No found en [HTTPPOST] del controlador

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Buen día

Ando empezando en asp.net y se me esta presentando un problema al que no logro encontrar la solución por que no comprendo para que funciona exactamente.

lo que pasa es que cuando envió un formulario al controlador el actionResult recibe un objeto.

```
 [HttpPost]// con esta linea se presenta el problema.
    public ActionResult SinRedimensionar(TrabajaImagen imagen)
    {


        if (imagen.Fichero != null && imagen.Fichero.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            try
            {
                Image.FromStream(imagen.Fichero.InputStream);

                string nombreFichero = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagen.Fichero.FileName) + "_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(imagen.Fichero.FileName);
                imagen.Fichero.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Imagenes"), nombreFichero));
                imagen.NombreFichero = nombreFichero;
            }
            catch 
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "La imagen seleccionada no es una imagen válida");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "No se ha seleccionado ninguna imagen");
        }

        return View(imagen);
    }
```

cuando le agrego el [HttpPost] me sale el error de no found 404. pero si se lo quito no. Y no logro comprender por que sucede esto, como podria solucionar esto y como es la forma correcta de hacer que funcione?

Cabe aclarar que desde la vista si estoy enviado información por el metodo post.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SinRedimensionar", "Fichero", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", role = "form" }))
```

{

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NombreFichero)

<div class="col-md-12">
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Subir" />
</div>

@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

}
agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: no veo en el html que definas ninguna archivo, que pasa si quitas el  enctype = "multipart/form-data"

Comment: si pones la vista completa, tendrás más ojos para debuggear :D crea otro public ActionResult SinRedimensionar{ return View();} y agrega [HTTPGet]

Answer (score 1):

Cuando envías el objeto al controlador en un action

```
public ActionResult SinRedimensionar(TrabajaImagen imagen);
```

El objeto lo estas enviado por POST, por lo menos, en los ejemplos que yo hago, si en el formulario le digo que se envíe por POST, no es necesario que coloque el  `[HttpPost]` en el controlador ya que el envío del formulario busca el action por POST.

Al mandar todo el objeto puedes trabajar directamente con los datos ingresados en el formulario, sin tener que recuperarlos por el request. Si pudieras poner la vista completa o si tienes definido otro controlador con el mismo para el GET quizás podría ayudarte con el problema que te sale, espero te sirva.